# Question on proof that $\operatorname{PowerSet}(X)\subset X $ is false for any $X$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking at some beginner set theory proofs in [this online  text](http://jianfeishen.weebly.com/uploads/4/7/2/6/4726705/set-theory.pdf).

One question I have is on exercise 6 (1.3.6) on page 2):

Prove that   $\mathcal P(X) \subset  X$ is false for any $X$.

The given answer is basically as follows:

> Proof. Let $X$ be an arbitrary set; then there exists a set
>
> $$Y = \{ u \in X :    u \notin u \}.$$
>
> Obviously, $Y\subset  X$, so  $Y\in\mathcal P(X)$, by Axiom of Power Set. If $Y\in X$, then we have $Y\in Y \iff Y \notin Y$ (a contradiction).  This
>   proves that  $\mathcal P(X) \not\subset X$.

I understand how one arrives at a contradiction if one assumes 
that $Y\in X$.  But does $Y$ necessarily have to be an element of $X$?
What about the case in which

$$Y \notin X?$$

Don't we have to show a contradiction for that too?

Comment: We also have that the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is $2^{|X|}$, where $|X|$ is the cardinality of $X$. Since $|X|\ge 0$, the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(X) > |X|$. So, $\mathcal{P}(X)$ cannot possibly be a subset of $X$.

Comment: Cute. But too tricky for some introductory notes. At the very least, the construction of Y should probably have been given as a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Consider that you have defined $Y $ for a reason. Notably to show there is a subset of $\mathcal {P}(X) $ which is not an element of $X$.

Comment: Oh boy.. you point that out and now it seems so obvious !        I guess it's time for me to wrap up and sleep.    Thanks for your help  ;^)

Comment: @ChrisBedford Hehe don't worry about it. Multiple negations are a PITA at the best of times.